# Declare a variable local

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, when you create a new scope, a variable will be captured the first time it is assigned if it already exists in the outer scope, or it will be created locally. How to prevent a variable from being captured?

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"?

Comment: Make your question clear to us.. We are just guessing here, may be that guess is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you mean you would like `x=2; begin x=3 end; puts x` to return `2` instead of `3`?

Comment: Ruby scopes are not like C scopes. Mostly, you're supposed to ignore anything beyond global, class, or function scope. What are you trying to do? There is likely a work around or more Ruby-esque way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds of local scopes in Ruby: script bodies, class bodies, module bodies, method bodies, and lambda literals and block bodies. Script, class, module and method scopes don't nest anyway, so there is nothing you need to do.

Only blocks and lambda literals can nest, and there you can explicitly declare variables as local by appending them to the parameter list separated by a semicolon:

```
x, y, z = %i[x y z]

-> (m1, m2, o1=:o1, o2=:o2, *splat, m3, m4, 
      ok1: :ok1, mk1:, mk2:, ok2: :ok2, **ksplat, &blk; x, y) {
     Hash[local_variables.map {|var| [var, eval(var.to_s)] }]
}.(1, 2, 3, 4, mk1: 5, mk2: 6)
# => { x: nil, y: nil, z: :z, m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: :o1, o2: :o2, splat: [], 
#      m3: 3, m4: 4, ok1: :ok1, mk1: 5, mk2: 6, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a method, they do not have lexical scope:

```
x = 2

def foobar
  x = 123
end

foobar  #=> 123
x       #=> 2
```

However it is not clear what your goal is. If you describe your actual problem more clearly, we might come up with way better answers.